# Source for Giordano Bruno quote

Tags: quote, love

I see this quote oftentimes attributed to Giordano Bruno but I cannot find it's source:
“I saw that the Sun was just another star. And the stars were other Suns, each escorted by other Earths like our own.

“The revelation of this immensity was like falling in love.”

Comment: Lovely. But it really works no matter who said it. No authority is needed for truth.